# Cardinality of $P(P(P(\phi)))=$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I came across a question on sets, where the cardinality of the following set has to be found:
$$P(P(P(A \times \phi)))$$
Where $|A|=m$.

A [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3712867/a-phi-then-npppa) has already been asked on this platform; however, I could not find a satisfactory answer. My chain of thought is as follows:

It is known that $|P(X)|=2^{|X|}$, where $X$ is a finite set. Which means the question above can be solved as follows:

$$\begin{align*}
|P(P(P(A \times \phi)))|
&=|P(P(P(\phi)))|\\
&=|P(P(\{\phi,\{\phi\}\}))|\\
&=|P(\{\phi,\{\phi\},\{\{\phi\}\},\{\phi,\{\phi\}\}\})|\\
&=|\{\phi,\{\phi\},\{\{\{\phi\}\}\},\{\{\phi,\{\phi\}\}\},...\}|
\end{align*}$$

Which should overall give 16 elements. A shorter method to go through this is using the formula $|P(X)|=2^{|X|}$. Which, I think, should again give 16 as seen above. **However, the actual answer is 4, and I don't understand why that is the case.**

Note: $|X|$ is the same as the cardinality of that set. I'm clarifying the notation since I believe $n(X)$ is the more commonly used notation.

Comment: How did $A$ just disappear?

Comment: Because $A \times \varnothing = \varnothing$ for any set $A$.

Comment: Next, you say $P(\varnothing) = \{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\}$. Examine this again.

Comment: @GEdgar Wouldn't the power set of $\phi$, that is, $P(\phi)=\{\phi,\{\phi\}\}$, as in all of $\phi$'s subsets?

Comment: $\{\varnothing\}$ is not a subset of $\varnothing$. $\varnothing$ is, but the set containing it is not.

Comment: @PrincessEev but then wouldn't the cardinality of the entire expression just be 1, where the recurring element is $\phi$?

Comment: No, because $$\mathcal{P}(\{\varnothing\}) = \{\color{blue}{\varnothing},\color{red}{\{\varnothing\}}\}$$

The blue since $\varnothing$ is a subset of any set, and the red because any set is a subset of itself. (That is, $\color{blue}{\varnothing \subseteq \{\varnothing\}}$ and $\color{red}{\{\varnothing\} \subseteq \{\varnothing\}}$.)

Comment: Of course the one-element set $\{\varnothing\}$ has more subsets than the 0-element set $\varnothing$.

Comment: Your 3rd display line of your attempted solution is erroneous. $\phi$ has just 1 subset, which is $\phi,$ so $P(\phi)=\{\phi\}$. So $P(P(P(\phi)))=P(P(\{\phi\}))$.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Ahh! Alright, that makes much more sense, thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For notational pleasantry, we'll adopt the convention $x \uparrow y := x^y$.

Then notice:

$$\begin{align*}
|\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(\varnothing)))|
&=2 \uparrow |\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(\varnothing))| \\
&=2 \uparrow (2 \uparrow|\mathcal{P}(\varnothing)|)\\
&=2 \uparrow (2 \uparrow (2 \uparrow |\varnothing|))\\
&=2 \uparrow (2 \uparrow (2 \uparrow 0))\\
&=2 \uparrow (2 \uparrow 1)\\
&=2 \uparrow 2 \\
&=4
\end{align*}
$$

Based on the comments, your errors seems to be in thinking $\mathcal{P}(\varnothing) = \{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\}$; here, you're mixing up the notion of the power set and (possibly?) the successor function. Recall that

$$\mathcal{P}(S) := \{ \text{sets } S \mid S \subseteq P \}$$

Note that $\varnothing$ the only subset here; $\{\varnothing\}$ is a set containing $\varnothing$, not a subset of it. (This is because $\varnothing \not \in \varnothing$.) That is, $\mathcal{P}(\varnothing) = \{\varnothing\}$ (a cardinality of $1=2^0$).